# how to get env_vars with nginx UWSGI_SETENV in uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

my nginx conf:

```
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /usr;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi-python/uwsgi/socket;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /var/www/my_site;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT my_site:app;
    uwsgi_param SERVER_NAME my_site;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_SETENV DEPLOY_VERSION=Development;
}
```

my uwsgi para:

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --master --processes 2 --logdate --chmod-socket=666 --uid www --gid www --limit-as 512 --harakiri 60 --max-requests 1000 --no-orphans —-reload-os-env --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi-python/uwsgi.log --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi-python/uwsgi/pid --socket /var/run/uwsgi-python/uwsgi/socket --xmlconfig /etc/uwsgi-python/apps-enabled/uwsgi.xml
```

uwsgi xml:

```
<uwsgi>
<master/>
<vhost/>
<memory-report/>
<no-site/>
</uwsgi>
```

In my flask app

```
print os.environ.get('DEPLOY_VERSION', 'NONE')  #pring NONE
```

How I can get the env_vars?

Maybe I can not get the env_vars setting by UWSGI_SETENV in <vhost/><no-site/> mode?

btw: How you deploy multi version(Development/Beta/Release) of app in one machine without virtual env?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

> uwsgi_param UWSGI_SETENV DEPLOY_VERSION=Development;

You could set it as a per request variable in nginx: `uwsgi_param DEPLOY_VERSION 'Development';`

And then within Flask, access the variable via request.environ: `request.environ['DEPLOY_VERSION']`

(I had a similar problem and was pointed to the above solution on the uwsgi mailing list)

Comment: indeed; you probably *cannot* set environment variables for uwsgi from nginx; as nginx does not actually launch uwsgi, (uwsgi must already be running) and so there's not really an option to set them.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue defining environment configurations for a django Mezzanine CMS deployment.

As the DEPLOY_VERSION seems to target the underlying application and not the uWSGI service, I think the correct place to put it to be the uWSGI configuration file instead of the Nginx one.

Try changing the .xml file to:

```
<uwsgi>
<master/>
<vhost/>
<memory-report/>
<env>DEPLOY_VERSION=Development</env> <!-- this -->
<no-site/>
</uwsgi>
```